# Issues using PHP Trader Functions: Call to undefined function trader_ma()

Tags: php, unix, pecl, mamp, pear

I'm attempting to install the Trader extension on my mac, currently using MAMP. I believe the install was done correctly but can't seem to use them. Here is my feedback from terminal

> sudo  pecl install trader
>
> pecl/trader is already installed and is the same as the released version 0.4.0
>
> install failed

Based on that it shows that I have installed it. But here is what I get when trying to use one

> Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function trader_cci()

Running phpinfo(); tells me that my extension_dir is below

> extension_dir /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.6.2/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20131226/

Now, when I go dig into that directory I can't find trader.so at all so not sure if that could be causing this issue or not

[image]

Anybody have tips on a step I may have missed?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. If you can't see trader.so file into extension directory then your installation has not completed properly. You have to install it again.

Before doing so, you have to make some changes into your SIP settings. Follow the below steps to make changes.

1. Reboot your mac and hold <kbd>Command</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> keys simultaneously.  It will boot your OS into recovery mode.
2. when you see OS utilities screen, pull down utilities menu and select terminal.
3. type below command `csrutil disable` and hit enter. It will disable your mac's SIP.
4. then reboot your mac using `reboot` command.

Try to install trader once again. After successful installation, change your SIP settings and enable SIP. This is to secure your machine so don't forget enable it.

Hope this will help you... :)

Comment: SIP does not protect the `/Applications/MAMP` directory. There's no reason to disable it here, and doing so may cause other problems down the road.